# Problemas con proyecto C#

Tags: c#

Buenas la empresa me ha pasado un proyecto que hizo un compañero en C#, el problema lo tengo al abrir este que nos genera un error ..

> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Error     Error al restaurar el paquete NuGet para el proyecto
>   Dominio.Tests: No se encuentra la versión '4.4.0' del paquete
>   'EntityFramework'.   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\NuGetPackages: El paquete 'EntityFramework.4.4.0' no se encontró
>   en el origen 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: El paquete
>   'EntityFramework.4.4.0' no se encontró en el origen
>   'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.

En si este proyecto funcionaba perfectamente, ahora necesitamos hacer modificaciones pero al abrirlo en visual 2017 nos genera este error hemos probado con intentar recuperar y restaurar y nos genera lo mismo, si intentamos actualizar EF no nos lo permite, he probado varias cosas pero nos sigue dando error.

Es urgente gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Lo primero, _es urgente_ no nos dice nada. Para cualquiera que quiera perder algo de su tiempo en ayudarte (gratis), no es urgente, lo hará cuando considere :) . En cuanto a tu problema, has intentado cambiar la plataforma de destino del proyecto y poner Net 4?

Comment: si pero nos sigue arrojando el mismo error, si digo lo de urgente es porque he realizado esta consulta en otro foro y nadie contesta aunque sea para decir no se me ocurre algo, por eso. Lo siento ;)

Comment: No te preocupes, todos comentemos errores. En principio, lo que necesitarías es EF 5. Intenta ejecutar esto en la consola de Nuget `Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0.0` o buscar Entity Framework en el nuget

Comment: Install-Package : Faltan algunos paquetes NuGet en la solución. Los paquetes se tienen que restaurar para crear el gráfico de dependencias. Restaure los paquetes antes de realizar la operacion...

Comment: Si tienes algo mas de información, no la pongas en los comentarios. Pulsa en [edit] y añade ahi todo lo que consideres importante, por ejemplo que has intentado y que errores te da

Comment: la cuestion es que he probado esto y sigue dandome error... si lo hago asi me da este, aunque instale los nuget y si le doy a ejecutar me da el de EF ... Es como un bucle y necesito hacerlo trabajar en c# y no hay manera

Comment: Mira a ver si esto te ayuda. [Habilitar restauracion de paquetes nuget](https://diegobersano.com.ar/2014/07/17/habilitar-restauracion-de-paquetes-nuget/)

Comment: ok voy a probar leyendo esto y os comento gracias ;)

Comment: Restauramos y nos vuelca el mismo error de que no se encuentra la version del paquete EntityFramework... Es como un bucle constante nos arroja un error u otro

Comment: Me sucedió lo mismo cuando (exactamente el mismo caso), mi error fue que la version de nuget que poseía, no era complatible con la version de visual studio ni de mi windows(32 ó 64 bits), los resolví descargando una version compatible de su pagina oficial [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)

Comment: Acabo de instalar los nuget.exe y sigo conel mismo error me dice que me faltan paquetes .. restauro ya con los paquetes y con los que hay en línea y me salta el error de EF.

Comment: @dunia48 pues sin tener acceso al proyecto, a mi al menos no se me ocurre nada mas. Limpiar la solucion y tratar de empezar de cero tal vez..

Comment: @Pikoh si me das un sitio donde enviarte copia comprimida te envio y le echas un ojo si quieres porque yo ando probando todo y no consigo salir del bucle

Comment: El problema es que no tengo vs2017, trabajo con 2015...tal vez alguien que tenga 2017 pueda probarlo.

Comment: con vsto 2015 salta el mismo bucle

Comment: Pues si el proyecto no contiene ningún "secreto empresarial", súbelo a algín lado y tal vez podamos echar un vistazo a ver si damos con ello.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si el proyecto **Dominio.Tests** esta haciendo referencia a otro proyecto que sí utiliza EntityFramework, el proyecto **Dominio.Tests** tambien debe de tener EntityFramework importado para poder funcionar. Segun veo  este es un proyecto Test y lo mas seguro es que estas haciendo Unit Test a un proyecto llamado **Dominio** que sí utiliza EF.

Comment: @Einer cierto vemos este error pero al intentar solventarlo y compilar nos sigue dando error, me sabrías sugerir alguna otra idea. Gracias

Comment: Creo que llege tarde, pero yo lo que hice fue entrar al administrar paquetes nuget y actualice a la ultima vesrion de Entity framework

Answer (score 2):

Yo tengo exactamente el mismo error. Por alguna razón en Visual Studio 2017 como que hay algún error en las dependencias.

Yo aún no he resuelto el problema pero investigando encontré que puedes hacer lo siguiente.

Herramientas > Administrador de paquetes de NuGet > Configuración del administrador de paquetes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente vista valida que los checkbox estén seleccionados como se ve a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenta, quizá tu problema pueda solucionarse de esta manera. Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que encontré la solución al problema.

Resulta que en tu proyecto hay un archivo que se llama "packages.config", en el cual se encuentran las configuraciones de los paquetes que utiliza tu proyecto.

Bien, en este archivo tiene que haber una línea designada para EntityFramework, en mi caso era para otro paquete. Lo solucione borrando la línea y compilando de nuevo el proyecto. Te dejo capturas de lo que hice.

Este es el archivo que debes modificar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el contenido del archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi caso esta es la línea que debo eliminar. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La eliminas, guardas los cambios y compilas de nuevo el proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Hola si estas utilizando asp. net core entonces la solucion es actualizar las bibliotecas y que todas tengan la misma version, yo actulice y luego de compilar me permitio actualizar el Scaffolding.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto se asemeja mas a un comentario